# Is it possible to embed an http link in a vbscript message box?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, vbscript

I would like to direct the user to an appropriate download link per case. Can I embed a clickable link in a vbs message box? Or, is there a cleaner way to solve this problem?

```
 select case FSO.GetFileVersion(strCorLib)
            Case "2.0.50727.42"
                strNETVersion = strNETVersion & " SP0 (not so good!)"
            Case "2.0.50727.1433"
                strNETVersion = strNETVersion & " SP1 (this will work)" 
            Case "2.0.50727.3053"
                strNETVersion = strNETVersion & " SP2 (this is good)"
            end select

            strNetVersion = strNETVersion & ", " & FSO.GetFile(strCorLib).DateLastModified
        else
            strNETVersion = ".NET 2.0 not installed"
        end if
        sayit strNetVersion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible using a standard msgbox... you'd have to roll your own...

Check out [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/oct04/hey1022.mspx) for more info...

Comment: objShell.Run(http://www.alinktosendusertodownload.com) works well enough for me until I absolutely must come up with a cleaner solution. I will have to up-vote you for that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When I code VBScript, I use something like that. IMO it's a cleaner way.

```
iRes = objShell.Popup("Something not found." & vbNewLIne & _
    "Without that the world wont be saved." & vbNewLIne & _
    "Download it now?",, "Required software is missing", 4+48)    ' 4=MB_YESNO, 48=MB_ICONEXCLAMATION
if iRes = 6 then     ' 6=IDYES
    objShell.Run("http://www.microsoft/com/...")
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check [ShowModalDialog](http://blog.davidkaspar.com/archives/2005/10/showmodaldialog-in-firefox-and-frames.php).  It allows exactly what you want, but like the link from John it's an IE only solution.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery and a little markup to solve this problem. jQuery not even necessary, but saves coding.